# Scala: Can I reproduce anonymous class creation with a factory method?

Tags: scala, factory, anonymous-class

As far as I understand it, Scala creates an anonymous class if I create a class using the `new` keyword and follow the class name with a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  def doStuff() { 
    // ... 
  }
}

val mc = new MyClass {
  doStuff()
}
```

The nice thing being that all the code in the constructor is in the scope of the new object.

Is there a way I can reproduce this syntax where the class is created by a factory method rather than the `new` keyword?  i.e. make the following code work:

```
val mf = new MyFactory

val mc = mf.MyClass { 
  doStuff() 
}
```

I can't find a way to do it but Scala has so much to it that this might be pretty easy!

Using an `import` as suggested by @Ricky below I can get:

```
val mf = MyFactory;
val mc = mf.MyClass

{
  import mc._
  doStuff()
}
```

(Where the blank line before the block is needed) but that code block is not a constructor.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to add statements to be run (like `doStuff()` in your example) or entire field definitions? The former is easy via passing a call-by-need block, the latter sounds very tricky...

Comment: I want to be able to add code that is automagically within scope of the object being created, whether that is calling methods or accessing fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but you still have to keep the `new` keyword, and create the nested class as a path-dependent type:

```
class Bippy(x: Int) {
  class Bop {
    def getIt = x
  }
}

val bip = new Bippy(7)
val bop = new bip.Bop

bop.getIt // yields 7

val bop2 = new bip.Bop{ override def getIt = 42 }

bop2.getIt // yields 42
```

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't used path-dependent types so I need to think this through to see if it does what I want.

Comment: It allows you to create an anonymous subclass of some given type, but still within the surrounds of some outer context (call it a factory if you wish).  That *felt* like it's what you were after :)

Comment: That certainly does sound like it.  Time for me to learn path-dependent types in earnest then.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I was still thinking about it.  The one problem I can see is when a factory generates a different class depending on the calling object.  For example when you have a set of classes that extend a base class, each of which has a different delegate but there is a single factory that returns the delegates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. However, a common pattern is to add a parameter to factory methods which takes a function modifying the created object:

```
trait MyClass {
  var name = ""
  def doStuff():Unit
}

class Foo extends MyClass {
  def doStuff() { println("FOO: " + name) }
}

trait MyClassFactory {
  def make: MyClass
  def apply( body: MyClass => Unit ) = {
    val mc = make
    body(mc)
    mc
  }
}

object FooFactory extends MyClassFactory {
  def make = new Foo
}
```

You can then create and modify instance with a syntax close to your example:

```
val foo = FooFactory { f=>
  f.name = "Joe"
  f.doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking to mix in a trait.  Instead of calling myFactoryMethod(classOf[Foo]] which ideally would do (if Scala permitted it):

```
new T {
  override def toString = "My implementation here."
}
```

you can instead write

```
trait MyImplementation {
  override def toString = "My implementation here."
}

new Foo with MyImplementation
```

However, if you are just looking to get the members of the new object accessible without qualification, remember you can import from any stable identifier:

```
val foo = new Bar
import foo._
println(baz) //where baz is a member of foo.
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I understood you correctly, the problem I can see with using a trait is that the factory would need to know what trait to apply, but maybe I can tell it that?

On your second point I found that I could use an import like this:

    val mf = MyFactory
    val mc = mf.MyClass

    {
      import mc._
      doStuff()
    }

(Where the blank line before the block is needed) but that code block is not a constructor.

Comment: The code got a bit mangled there so I've added something to my original question to explain where I got using `import`.  Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding the factory knowing what trait to apply, I thought you could do without the factory and just write new Foo with MyImplementation.  Mixing in a trait is not something that can be deferred until runtime, as it involves bytecode generation, and Scala does not provide a custom classloader.